# Parsing mutiple items using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse HTML from a website, where there are multiple elements having the same class ID. I can't seem to find a solution; I manage to get one item but not all of them.

Here's a bit of the HTML I'm trying to parse :

```
<h1>Synonymes travail</h1>
<div class="container-bloc1">
    <strong> Nom</strong>
    <br/>
    -
    <i><a class="lien2" href="/fr/accouchement.html"> accouchement </a></i>
    :
    <a class="lien3" href="/fr/gésine.html"> gésine</a>
    <br/>
    -
    <i> <a class="lien2" href="/fr/action.html">  action </a></i>
    :
    <a class="lien3" href="/fr/activité.html"> activité</a>
    ,
    <a class="lien3" href="/fr/labeur.html"> labeur</a>
</div>
```

In Python, I wrote it like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get("http://www.synonymes.net/fr/travail.html").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

for synonyme in soup.find_all("div", class_="container-bloc1"):
    print(synonyme)

synonymesdumot = synonyme.find("a", class_="lien2").text
    print(synonymesdumot)

for synonymesautres in synonyme.find_all("a", class_="lien3").text:
    print(synonymesautres)
```

The first part is working, since there is only one "lien2" in the HTML file. I could do the same for "lien3" but I'd only get one item, and I want all of them.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you use `.text` on a collection of multiple elements, as you are doing here. Does it work if you just loop with `for synonymesautres in synonyme.find_all("a", class_="lien3"):` and inside it do `print(synonymesautres.text)`?

Comment: It's working now… What a stupid mistake! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you the code as is in your question, you run into an `AttributeError` because the output of `.find_all()` is a collection of tags (a `ResultSet` more specifically) that has no attribute `text`; but each of its elements, which are of `type bs4.Element.Tag`, do. So you need to get the `text` attribute for each of the tags **inside** the for loop:

```
for synonymesautres in synonyme.find_all("a", class_="lien3"):
    print(synonymesautres.text)
```

Output:

```
le
travail
manque
de
travail
travail
fatigant
```